# Unable to see tables in a schema on snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have given usage privileges to the database, warehouse, and all schemas
as:

```
grant usage on database DATA__DEV  to role DEV__RO_ROLE;
grant usage on all schemas DATA__DEV  to role DEV__RO_ROLE;
grant select on all tables in schema DATA__DEV.PITK_DEV  to role 
DEV__RO_ROLE;
```

I am not able to see all the tables across any schema. Kindly tell me what privilege I should give so that the user can access all schemas and, view-only access to tables/views.

Thanks,
Xi

Comment: It needs select priv. grant select on all tables in schema schema_name...

Comment: Tried it said Statement executed successfully. 0 objects affected.

Comment: Are you the schema owner and I believe you have tables in the underlying schema?

Comment: yes, If I  change role, I am able to see  tables in that schema

Comment: And are you issuing the grants connected as the role of schema owner? That is when you do select current_role(); you should see the schema owner role as output.

Comment: If you ran “grant select on all tables in schema…” and it said 0 objects affected then either there aren’t any tables in that schema or you’re not running it with a role that doesn’t have the required access to the tables.

Comment: I have  executed select schemas and got the owner from them and I have changed my role to that , still it gives same error

Comment: As you are getting 0 objects when executing the “grant select on all tables in schema…”  , can you run "show tables in schema_name" and see if you are seeing the tables.

Comment: @HimanshuKandpal yes I am able to see all tables

Comment: These are all external tables, will this affect?

Comment: can you see if this statement, returns the table "select * from  information_schema.external_tables; "

Comment: yes I am able to see tables

Comment: Hi , can you just try granting SELECT access to one table and see if it works .

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing this

```
grant usage on database DATA__DEV to role DEV__RO_ROLE;
grant usage on ALL SCHEMAS IN DATABASE DATA__DEV to role DEV__RO_ROLE;
grant select on all tables in schema DATA__DEV.PITK_DEV to role DEV__RO_ROLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

All securable database objects (such as TABLE, FUNCTION, FILE FORMAT, STAGE, SEQUENCE, etc.) are contained within a SCHEMA object within a DATABASE. As a result, to access database objects, in addition to the privileges on the specific database objects, users must be granted the USAGE privilege on the container database and schema.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-considerations.html#accessing-database-objects

These grants should be through the owner's role to have the underlying objects to get affected.

You could check the difference between the roles(which lists the objects and the role which does not list) and check the differences to find the missing privilege using the below command

```
SHOW GRANTS TO ROLE <ROLE_NAME>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Even after granting the database, schema, table permissions via role to user if you are not able to access the snowflake tables then you need to switch the  default role to the role which have access to the snowflake tables